# How to declare iOS application sharing extension to accept contacts from native Contacts app

Tags: ios, xcode

I have set NSExtensionActivationRule -s for my application sharing extension, to support sharing of: Images, videos, text and URL -s. As on following image

[image]

I need to add rule to accept sharing of contacts, from native Contacts app, in this extension.
Is there any solution for this?

**Solution based on @Mahipal Singh answer**

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
            <string>
                SUBQUERY (
                extensionItems, $extensionItem,
                SUBQUERY (
                $extensionItem.attachments, $attachment,
                ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.vcard" ||
                ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.image" ||
                ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.movie" ||
                ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.plain-text" ||
                ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.url"
                ).@count == 1
                ).@count > 0
            </string>
        </dict>
        <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
        <string>MainInterface</string>
        <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
    </dict>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/27383

```
  <key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
        <string>
            SUBQUERY (
            extensionItems, $extensionItem,
            SUBQUERY (
            $extensionItem.attachments, $attachment,
            ANY $attachment.registeredTypeIdentifiers UTI-CONFORMS-TO "public.vcard"
            ).@count >= 1
            ).@count > 0
        </string>
    </dict>
    </dict>
```

See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html) for the available keys. Look for NSExtensionActivationRule.

Comment: Never in a million years. Thank you